# hadoop and elasticsearch integration

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch

I would like to integrate apache Hadoop and elasticsearch for my project.Where the data will be stored into HDFS at the same time will be also be available on elastic search. 
Any changes which I perform on the data in elastic search should also be reflected and stored in the HDFS. So basically I am looking for bidirectional flow between elastic search and hdfs.   I have tried searching web for any useful documentation but didn't find anything helpful. Any help in this regard will be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by integration? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Don't except answers for such a broad question. Narrow it down, you will have the solution.

Comment: @Chiron I want to use elasticsearch and hadoop for my project. Elastic search will be used for all real time processing of data and at the same time data will be stored in Hadoop. This is my requirement as such . Any idea on this can be helpful.

Comment: @blackSmith please check my comments above if you can help on that.

Comment: First of all, Hadoop isn't for storing/persisting data.

Comment: @Chiron okies... Correct me if I am wrong. Hadoop is a framework which is used for storage and large-scale processing of data. This is my understanding as such.

Comment: Hadoop is framework for big/huge data crunching. HDFS is usually used for storing the output. Of course, other destinations are possible.

Comment: Thanks @Chiron for the info. If you could shed some light on the requirement that would be great . I am looking for any documentation on es-hadoop as it is named in the current elastic search industry.

Comment: Work on your question. It is really hard to know what do you want to achieve.

Comment: @Chiron have edited the question . Does it explain my requirement clear enough ..  Thanks

Comment: Whether its relevant or not to ur situation, all I know is that usually data is stored in HDFS and use elasticsearch to provide a quick search over them. I think ur flow was reverse before editing the question.

Answer (score 1):

See [Elasticsearch for hadoop](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/hadoop/) and [Map Reduce](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/mapreduce.html) You can index the data from HDFS into ES in real time for new, modified and deleted data. But from ES into HDFS may not possible, because HDFS is based on Write-once-read-many architecture [HDFS Design](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/hadoop/).